# How can I query OUT then IN traversal, in ArangoDB 3.2?

Tags: arangodb

I have the following graph structure. All vertexes are in the same collection, and all edges are in the same collection. From a particular start vertex (F), I want to return all the vertexes that are the result of going outwards once, then inwards once, so that I end up with, in the example, D and E.
 [image]

Answer (score 1):

Well after fooling with it for a while, this is what I came up with. Seems to work. Posting this in case someone else searches for a similar question.

```
 FOR v IN 1..1 OUTBOUND "Vertex/F" edges
  FOR vv IN 1..1 INBOUND v edges 
  FILTER vv._key != "F"
  Collect uniqueKeys = vv._key
  return uniqueKeys
```

The query take almost a millisecond for a small 8 vertex db, but I don't think I can do better.

Comment: Yes, this is right. Remember your query has access to v, e, p (rather than just v as you've used) which lets you perform queries from the paths returned, rather than the vertices. By using LAST(p.vertices) or FIRST(p.vertices) you can have more control over how your second query runs. But only if needed, what you did there works for 1 step out.